# Error in generating pdf

Tags: php, pdf

When I want to generate a PDF, this error-message box display appears:

> Can't write fo file var/www/vhosts/makeithappen.tmpsvr3.com.uk/httpdocs/survey Check that the process runing **PHP** has enough permission

Comment: I should think it is a permissions error, as the error says. If it is just a single instance, using `chmod` on the file would be enough to get this working. You'll need to be aware of the users/groups on the file in order to determine the correct permissions - I'd try `chmod 700 <file>` first, then `chmod 750 <file>` if that doesn't work. Always give the least permissions possible, to keep it secure - especially if you are on a shared host.

Comment: Also: if you have different processes creating files, you may need to use `chmod` in PHP in order to reset the permissions of the file every time you create it.